# Custom validation based on HTTP methods

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, spring-rest

I'm writing a Java based, Spring REST web service. I'm wondering if there is a way to exclude some object validations for `HTTP PATCH`.

Basically, what I need is to validate the same object differently for `HTTP POST` and for the `HTTP PATCH`. For example, when `HTTP POST` request is received i need to include `@NotNull` validation for fields, `HTTP PATCH` doesn't need to check if field is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bean Validation using groups.

```
@NotNull(groups=Group1.class)
private String field;

@NotNull(groups=Group2.class)
private String field;
```

You can see more here.

http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using